# Help with union of intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know nothing about intervals, and I need some help with them because I need them for some programming exercises.
Let's say that we have these 3 intervals:

[1,2)

(-1,0]

[-12,-4]

{if there is [ or ] it means it is included, if there is ( or ) it means it's excluded.}

Ok, because I don't know anything about intervals and need help with them, is it possible for someone to tell me what is the union between these 3 intervals equal to ?

I think it is: [-12,2). If I am wrong, why ?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  You are wrong because (-4,-1] and (0,1) are not included in the union

Comment: The intervals only coalesce if they overlap.  No two of these intervals overlap.  Draw a picture on a number line, and it will be plain.

Comment: to be clear, [ or ] means the end point is included; ( or ) means it's not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element $x$ is in an interval $[a,b]$ if $a \le x \le b$; the inequalities turn strict if the bounds are not included (open vs. closed) and you can mix; so e.g. $x \in (a,b] \iff a<x\le b$.

An element is in the **union** of these intervals:

> $$[1,2) \cup  (-1,0]  \cup [-12,-4]$$

if it is in (at least) one of the three intervals. So your answer:

> I think it is: [-12,2). If I am wrong, why ?

can't be right because, for example, $-3 \in [-12,2)$ (because $-12 \le -3 < 2$) but the number $-3$ is not in any of the three given intervals, since:

- $-3 \not\in [1,2)$
- $-3 \not\in (-1,0]$
- $-3 \not\in [-12,-4]$

---

Note that the union of intervals isn't necessarily an interval itself.

Comment: So, if I had these 3 intervals and I wanted to check is some number x in union of these 3 intervals, I would basically check if it is in any of intervals and if it is in any of these 3 intervals, it's in the union of them ?

Comment: Correct! Even for more general sets (not necessarily intervals which are 'special-shaped sets') that's how it works: an element is in the union of sets $A$ and $B$ if it is either in $A$ or in $B$ (or in both!). An element is _not_ in a union if it isn't in any of the 'united sets'.

Comment: Thank you! I never learned this in school but I needed it for some programming things, so you really  helped me out! Thank you again! :D

Comment: You're welcome; good luck!